# Blocked in my project with reinforcement learning.. any help?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I would like advice on a problem I'm trying to solve. I'm stuck...

Here's an example: I have continuous data from a person such as what was eaten for a week (calories, carbohydrates, protein and fat) and also the goal such as the desired weight.

I want to do an action (without prior training) based on the values and the goal. The actions will consist of decreasing/increasing the number of carbohydrates, lipids, proteins or calories.

I have started to use reinforcement training but I really don't know if it is the best approach? The goal of reinforcement learning will be to reach the desired body weight with all of the actions.

One action can have a positive impact for a while and maybe a negative impact afterwards.

For the decision making algorithm, I created my own... but I would like to use something else that is better... I'm stuck with the choice.

Thanks!

Comment: To me, this problem does not seem very appropriate for reinforcement learning, because it seems difficult to identify the effects of the actions on the level of achievement of the goal, due to the mixed factors and the temporal delay between them. Also, human health is a sensible thing, probably best monitored by a human expert, or at least with automated rules elaborated by a human expert.

Comment: Hello! thanks for your answer :) I will get more data to make better decisions (as much as I can). I am nutritionist and when taking a decision it is almost the same, you try to get a decision based on the information you get from the patient and other factors (blood work and so on...). Not that easy sometimes and you see the patient every week or every 2 weeks.